# How to turn a String from a .Txt Document to a Dictionary Vairable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import json

h = '{1":{"Name":"Teddies","Amount":6,"PPU":int(6),"CPU":int(4)},2:{"Name":"WoodenToys","Amount":0,"PPU":int(15) * int(1),"CPU":int(10)}}'

d = json.loads(h)

print(d[1]["Name"])
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON, so obviously `json.loads` isn't going to work. It's not valid python either, so something like `eval` isn't going to work either. Does your string really look like that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo at the beginning of your dict definition. 
The correct syntax should be: `h = '{"1":{"Name":"Teddies","Amount":6,"PPU":int(6),"CPU":int(4)},2:{"Name":"WoodenToys","Amount":0,"PPU":int(15) * int(1),"CPU": int(10)}}'`

You can use the `eval()` function for this, but beware cause it's not safe and hence not recommended.

Check out the `literal_eval()` function from the [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module instead.

You will have to lose the `int()` parsing or do it somehow before...